# FilterListView - Remove items from list that don't begin with supplied prefix

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-search

I've created a list view with filtering that operates well. However I was just wondering, how can I get my list view to remove items that don't begin with the supplied prefix as I type into my search view? As seen in the supplied screenshot, when I type in the letter 'p' none of my items begin with that letter but yet the list doesn't disappear.

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<Victoria> mData;
    private List<Victoria> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public ItemListAdapter (List<Victoria> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = new ArrayList(mData);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position).getItem();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getItem());
        holder.description.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getItemDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = new ArrayList(mData);
            } else {
                List<Victoria> resultList = new ArrayList<Victoria>();
                for (Victoria str : mData) {
                    if (str.getItemDescription().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0) {
                mFilteredData.clear();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<Victoria>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you'd either need to redo your `performFiltering` method to use `String.startsWith(prefix)` or create a new filtering method.

Comment: All the descriptions of your items contain the letter p (Europe Descri**p**tion, etc.), and you are filtering using `contains`. See the line `if (str.getItemDescription().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))`. It should be like Patrick says.

Comment: Silly me, that shoulda been `if (str.getItem()...` problem solved